# Call a ViewModel function from an HTML element rendered with KnockOutJs

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I am rendering HTML with a column data bound like this:

```
<td data-bind="html: content"></td>
```

In the ViewModel content can contain an element that should response to viewmodel events like click. An example can be:

```
<a href='#'><img src='../img/search.png' data-bind='click: function() { foo()  }' ></img></a>
```

in this case, the `foo()` funciton is not called. Neither `$root.foo()` or `$parent.foo()` (I am inside a foreach context.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Just to make it clear, have you tried this?

`<a href='#'><img src='../img/search.png' data-bind='click: $root.foo' ></img>`

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to say that the foo() function is a function.

What I mean by this is that you don't use the `function() {foo() } syntax`

You should be able to get it to work by just using the function call itself:

```
<a href='#'><img src='../img/search.png' data-bind='click:foo()' ></img></a>
```

Comment: You don't even need the parentheses, however the $root prefix is needed, because the snippet is used in a foreach.